# Get next bigger/smaller number with a given precession

Tags: math, rounding

Having a double precision number and desired rounding number, how do I get next `bigger/smaller rounded number` ?

**Sample**

```
N = 10.476
Prec = 0.25
Smaller = 10.25
Bigger = 10.50

N = 0.837
Prec = 0.005
Smaller = 0.835
Bigger = 0.840
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def round_smaller(n, prec)
  (n / prec).floor * prec
end

def round_bigger(n, prec)
  (n / prec).ceil * prec
end
```